# How to avoid gated clock on a flip-flop?

Tags: schematics, xilinx

I've read that it is a bad practice and I should use the enable signal.
Is it also a bad idea to connect a gated, divided clock signal to the enable input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best design practice is to connect all of the sequential logic in a specific partition of your design to a common clock. Then use combinatorial logic to interconnect all of the state flip-flops using clock enables, the D inputs and the J/K inputs of the flops. No logic gating of the clock should be needed.

Comment: I need 2 or 3 states in my design, where some of the flip-flops are enabled, some are not, and then the others. Should I use a counter to keep track of the state?

Comment: State machine design is a whole different question and should be submitted separately after you have researched the subject.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate a bit about *why* this is considered the best design practice. I think it would really make a useful addition to your answer. Thanks!